# postgresql ON CONFLICT with multiple constraints

Tags: postgresql, constraints

There is a constraint violation handling "On conflict" statement, working fine if i want to check 1 (!) constraint

For example :

```
 INSERT INTO my_table (co1,col2..colN) 
 VALUES (...) 
 ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING --or update
```

But if i have 2 constaints `unique(col1,col2)` and `unique(col5,col6,col7)` , the query below is not working :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (co1,col2..colN) 
VALUES (...) 
ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING --or update
ON CONFLICT (col5, col6, col7) DO NOTHING --or update
```

This raises the error, pointing on : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on". LINE _: on conflict (col5, col6, col7) do nothing`

How could i resolve using multiple constraint checking in one query?

Comment: In this use-case you could just not specify any constraints (ie `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`). In the general case (for instance doing nothing on 2 out of 3 constrains, or on 1 do nothing and the other one do an update), you would need to be able to know at planning-time whether those conflict or not (eg do you update or do you ignore). This, as far as I know, is not implemented (nor planned to be).

Comment: for my case i need to ignore all conflicts. Connecting via psycopg2 i can solve it via `try: query; except IntegrityError: rollback`, but seems this is bad solution, and there is probably sql way without using `conflict` statement, if conflict statement cannot resolve multiple constraint handling

Answer (score 2):

[As per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html):

> For `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, it is optional to specify a `conflict_target`; when omitted, conflicts with all usable constraints (and unique indexes) are handled. For `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, a `conflict_target` must be provided.

So, you can just write:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (co1,col2..colN) 
 VALUES (...) 
 ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

This doesn't work for `DO UPDATE`, though. However, we might soon get treated to the [standard SQL `MERGE` statement](https://www.depesz.com/2022/03/31/waiting-for-postgresql-15-add-support-for-merge-sql-command/) in PostgreSQL, in case of which you could do these more complex conflict resolutions manually.